# C++ -- what is wrong with this code?

Tags: c++

I can't seem to figure out what the issue is here:

```
if(temperature<=-173)
        cout << "Ethyl alcohol will freeze" << endl;
    else if (temperature >-173 && temperature<172)
        cout << "Ethyl alcohol will be liquid" << endl;
    else(temperature>=172)
        cout << "Ethyl alcohol will boil" << endl;
```

The error I get is

```
error: expected ';' before 'cout'
=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===
```

Comment: `else if (temperature>=172)`, or even simpler, just `else` to cover all other cases.

Comment: Also note you always should use `{}` blocks after `if/else` statements.

Comment: @πάντα ῥε: I strongly disagree... and it's totally inappropriate to give debatable style advice unrelated to the thrust of the question, (particularly useless for having no pros/cons).  I shouldn't have to clutter up this question just to prevent your advice from being read unopposed and mistaken for a universally accepted standard by later readers.

Answer (score 5):

Change:

```
else(temperature>=172)
```

to just:

```
else  // temperature >= 172
```

The former is not a valid `if` statement since it doesn't have `if` and, in any case, you've already covered the solid and liquid phases so the only thing *left* is gas (weird plasma states notwithstanding).

The reason you're getting the obscure error message is because:

```
 else(temperature>=172)
```

is actually quite valid (like `42;` is valid, but equally useless), executing `(temperature>=172)` as the `else` case, which simply evaluates the condition and throws it away.

But, in that case, it should have been terminated with a semicolon before the next statement, the `cout <<`. Hence the error:

```
expected ';' before 'cout'
```

Comment: I am assuming atmospheric pressure as well here

Answer (score 2):

You can't add a condition section directly after "else".

Change your code to match this:

```
if(temperature<=-173)
        cout << "Ethyl alcohol will freeze" << endl;
    else if (temperature >-173 && temperature<172)
        cout << "Ethyl alcohol will be liquid" << endl;
    else
        cout << "Ethyl alcohol will boil" << endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

The exact issue is that you are missing a `if` between the `else` and your condition `(temperature>=172)`.

But you could also write without condition:

```
if(temperature<=-173)
   cout << "Ethyl alcohol will freeze" << endl;
else if (temperature >-173 && temperature<172)
   cout << "Ethyl alcohol will be liquid" << endl;
else
   cout << "Ethyl alcohol will boil" << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

So to elaborate on an above answer, what he means is this:

```
if(temperature<=-173)
   cout << "Ethyl alcohol will freeze" << endl;
else if (temperature >-173 && temperature<172)
   cout << "Ethyl alcohol will be liquid" << endl;
else if (temperature >= 172)
   cout << "Ethyl alcohol will boil" << endl;
```

but your better off taking my first answer and saving a few bytes of processing.